# get firebase data through cloud functions without any trigger

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

can I use cloud function to get data from a specific firebase database node? 
if there is a node (Car) with child (price) having value ($1000). how can I get this car value by cloud function? I have searched a lot but only able to find functions which work on triggers like onCreate, onUpdate, etc. But how to just simply fetch data without any trigger?

Comment: You can create basic function that receives get requests and returns cars. ex: `yourfrebaseip/cars`. Link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Define an an [HTTP trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).
2. Code that trigger to query Realtime Database using the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start).
3. Gather the fetched data into some variable, in the format you would like to serialize back to the client.
4. Send the database back to the client using the provided Response object passed to the trigger.
5. In the client, invoke that HTTP trigger using the URL it was assigned, and parse the data returned from step 4.

Answer (score 0):

You need initial the firebase first

```
  // Set the configuration for your app
  // TODO: Replace with your project's config object
  var config = {
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  // Get a reference to the database service
  var database = firebase.database();
```

and then read the data:

```
var carRef = database().ref('Car/);
carRef.on('price', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

more information, please check the firebase official document.

Comment: Yes exactly what Doug Stevenson had suggested. Anyway, thank you for your response.

Comment: Now just wondering how to fetch this data in android though this generated url? is it returning data in json format?